# What does the "@" symbol do in PowerShell?

Tags: syntax, powershell

I've seen the `@` symbol used in PowerShell to initialise arrays.

What exactly does the `@` symbol denote and where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

PowerShell will actually treat any comma-separated list as an array:

```
"server1","server2"
```

So the @ is optional in those cases. However, for associative arrays, the @ is required:

```
@{"Key"="Value";"Key2"="Value2"}
```

Officially, @ is the "array operator." You can read more about it in the documentation that installed along with PowerShell, or in a book like "Windows PowerShell: TFM," which I co-authored.

Comment: Make sure to check out Jeffrey Snover's answer below... @ is more than just an array identifier.

Answer (score 140):

In PowerShell V2, @ is also the [Splat operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6).

```
PS> # First use it to create a hashtable of parameters:
PS> $params = @{path = "c:\temp"; Recurse= $true}
PS> # Then use it to SPLAT the parameters - which is to say to expand a hash table 
PS> # into a set of command line parameters.
PS> dir @params
PS> # That was the equivalent of:
PS> dir -Path c:\temp -Recurse:$true
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for: this operator is used in the splat context in Azure Resource Group deployment scripts.

Answer (score 108):

While the above responses provide *most* of the answer it is useful--even this late to the question--to provide the full answer, to wit:

**Array sub-expression** (see [about_arrays](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx))

Forces the value to be an array, even if a singleton or a null, e.g. `$a = @(ps | where name -like 'foo')`

**Hash initializer** (see [about_hash_tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx))

Initializes a hash table with key-value pairs, e.g. 
`$HashArguments = @{ Path = "test.txt"; Destination = "test2.txt"; WhatIf = $true }`

**Splatting** (see [about_splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx))

Let's you invoke a cmdlet with parameters from an array or a hash-table rather than the more customary individually enumerated parameters, e.g. using the hash table just above, `Copy-Item @HashArguments`

**Here strings** (see [about_quoting_rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx))

Let's you create strings with easily embedded quotes, typically used for multi-line strings, e.g.:

```
$data = @"
line one
line two
something "quoted" here
"@
```

Because this type of question (*what does 'x' notation mean in PowerShell?*) is so common here on StackOverflow as well as in many reader comments, I put together a lexicon of PowerShell punctuation, just published on Simple-Talk.com. Read all about @ as well as % and # and $_ and ? and more at [The Complete Guide to PowerShell Punctuation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/the-complete-guide-to-powershell-punctuation/). Attached to the article is this wallchart that gives you everything on a single sheet:
[image]

Comment: Way better than accepted answer, actually provides more complete answer and links to documentation.

Answer (score 31):

You can also wrap the output of a cmdlet (or pipeline) in `@()` to ensure that what you get back is an array rather than a single item.

For instance, dir usually returns a list, but depending on the options, it might return a single object. If you are planning on iterating through the results with a foreach-object, you need to make sure you get a list back.  Here's a contrived example:

```
$results = @( dir c:\autoexec.bat)
```

One more thing... an empty array (like to initialize a variable) is denoted `@()`.

Comment: [array]$a syntax is somewhat clearer, visually, but good tip.

Answer (score 12):

**The Splatting Operator**

To create an array, we create a variable and assign the array. Arrays are noted by the "@" symbol. Let's take the discussion above and use an array to connect to multiple remote computers:

```
$strComputers = @("Server1", "Server2", "Server3")<enter>
```

They are used for arrays and hashes.

[PowerShell Tutorial 7: Accumulate, Recall, and Modify Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102083107/http://www.powershellpro.com:80/powershell-tutorial-introduction/variables-arrays-hashes/)

[Array Literals In PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/array-literals-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps to understand it a bit better.
You can store "values" within a key and return that value to do something.
In this case I have just provided @{a="";b="";c="";} and if not in the options i.e "keys" (a, b or c) then don't return a value

```
$array = @{
a = "test1";
b = "test2";
c = "test3"
}

foreach($elem in $array.GetEnumerator()){
    if ($elem.key -eq "a"){
        $key = $elem.key
        $value = $elem.value
    }
    elseif ($elem.key -eq "b"){
        $key = $elem.key
        $value = $elem.value
    }
    elseif ($elem.key -eq "c"){
        $key = $elem.key
        $value = $elem.value
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "No other value"
    }

    Write-Host "Key: " $key "Value: " $value 
}
```