# powershell: script with variable args

Tags: powershell, args

I want to start a script1.ps1 out of an other script with arguments stored in a variable.

> `$para = "-Name name -GUI -desc ""this is the description"" -dryrun"
>
>   . .\script1.ps1 $para`

The args I get in script1.ps1 looks like:

> args[0]: -Name name -GUI -desc "this is the description" -dryrun

so this is not what I wanted to get.
Has anyone a idea how to solve this problem?
thx lepi

PS: It is not sure how many arguments the variable will contain and how they are going to be ranked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Invoke-Expression` is another aternative:

```
$para = '-Name name -GUI -desc "this is the description" -dryrun'
Invoke-Expression -Command ".\script1.ps1 $para"
```

Comment: thx, the result is at the end the same but this is the real nice and short variant!

Answer (score 7):

You need to use *splatting operator*. Look at [powershell team blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-and-why-to-use-splatting-passing-switch-parameters/) or here at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363884/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-powershell).

Here is an example:

```
@'
param(
  [string]$Name,
  [string]$Street,
  [string]$FavouriteColor
)
write-host name $name
write-host Street $Street
write-host FavouriteColor $FavouriteColor
'@ | Set-Content splatting.ps1

# you may pass an array (parameters are bound by position)
$x = 'my name','Corner'
.\splatting.ps1 @x

# or hashtable, basically the same as .\splatting -favouritecolor blue -name 'my name'
$x = @{FavouriteColor='blue'
  Name='my name'
}
.\splatting.ps1 @x
```

In your case you need to call it like this:

```
$para = @{Name='name'; GUI=$true; desc='this is the description'; dryrun=$true}
. .\script1.ps1 @para
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped. If you are satisfied with the answer(s), you can close the questions by accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Where the _splatting operator_? There's no operator here this just happens to be the way PowerShell processes the commands... i.e. it's a feature, not an operator.