# What is the @ parameter?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, few programs starts with a `@'` and ends with `'@`, but when I type `@'` and press enter in the PowerShell prompt it throws an error. Can anyone explain how can I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "@" symbol do in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363884/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-powershell)

Comment: Typing `@'` by itself in powershell shouldn't get you an error. It should get you the continuation prompt (`>> `).

Comment: @elssar No, not `@` this is asking about the `@'`/`'@` pair.

Comment: To get help with an error: show the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is @” operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008511/what-is-operator)

Answer (score 8):

`@'...'@` and `@"..."@` are "Here Strings" (documented in [about_quoting_rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx)):

> HERE-STRINGS
>
> The quotation rules for here-strings are slightly different.
>
> A here-string is a single-quoted or double-quoted string in 
>       which quotation marks are interpreted literally. A here-string can 
>       span multiple lines. All the lines in a here-string are interpreted
>       as strings even though they are not enclosed in quotation marks.
>
> Like regular strings, variables are replaced by their values in 
>       double-quoted here-strings. In single-quoted here-strings, variables
>       are not replaced by their values.
>
> You can use here-strings for any text, but they are particularly
>       useful for the following kinds of text:
>
> ```
> -- Text that contains literal quotation marks
> -- Multiple lines of text, such as the text in an HTML or XML document
> -- The Help text for a script or function
> ```
>
> A here-string can have either of the following formats, where  
>       represents the linefeed or newline hidden character that is added when
>       you press the ENTER key.
>
> Double-quotes:
>
> ```
>    @"<Enter>
>     <string> [string] ...<Enter>
>     "@
> ```
>
> Single-quotes:
>
> ```
>    @'<Enter>
>     <string> [string] ...<Enter>
>     '@
> ```
>
> In either format, the closing quotation mark must be the first character 
>       in the line.
>
> A here-string contains all the text between the two hidden characters.
>       In the here-string, all quotation marks are interpreted literally.
>       For example:
>
> ```
>    @"
>     For help, type "get-help"
>     "@
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
>    For help, type "get-help"
> ```
>
> Using a here-string can simplify using a string in a command. For 
>       example:
>
> ```
>    @"
>     Use a quotation mark (') to begin a string.
>     "@
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
>    Use a quotation mark (') to begin a string.
> ```
>
> In single-quoted here-strings, variables are interpreted literally and 
>       reproduced exactly. For example:
>
> ```
>    @'
>     The $profile variable contains the path
>     of your Windows PowerShell profile.
>     '@
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
>    The $profile variable contains the path
>     of your Windows PowerShell profile.
> ```
>
> In double-quoted here-strings, variables are replaced by their values. 
>       For example:
>
> ```
>    @" 
>     Even if you have not created a profile,
>     the path of the profile file is:
>     $profile.
>     "@
> ```
>
> The output of this command is:
>
> ```
>    Even if you have not created a profile,
>     the path of the profile file is:
>     C:\Users\User01\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1.
> ```
>
> Here-strings are typically used to assign multiple lines to
>       a variable. For example, the following here-string assigns a
>       page of XML to the $page variable.
>
> ```
>    $page = [XML] @"
>     <command:command xmlns:maml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10"
>     xmlns:command="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10" 
>     xmlns:dev="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/2004/10">
>     <command:details>
>             <command:name>
>                    Format-Table
>             </command:name>
>             <maml:description>
>                 <maml:para>Formats the output as a table.</maml:para>
>             </maml:description>
>             <command:verb>format</command:verb>
>             <command:noun>table</command:noun>
>             <dev:version></dev:version>
>     </command:details>
>     ...
>     </command:command>
>     "@
> ```
>
> Here-strings are also a convenient format for input to the 
>       ConvertFrom-StringData cmdlet, which converts here-strings to hash 
>       tables. For more information, see ConvertFrom-StringData.

Answer (score 3):

`@'` and `'@` mark the beginning and end of a [Here-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx). Typing `@'` and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a PowerShell console should normally give you the line continuation prompt (`>>`):

```
PS C:> @'
>> _
```

If you get an error you most likely didn't type a single (or double) quote, but a forward or backtick or some kind of typographic quote. If that's the case you should be getting an "unrecognized token" error like this:

```
PS C:\> @´
At line:1 char:1
+ @´
+ ~
Unrecognized token in source text.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```