# How to read in key-value pairs as a template for String processing with PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, templates, key-value, text-processing

Very concisely writing a here string to file:

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> @'
>> foo : {abc}
>> bar : {123}
>> baz : {a1b2c3}
>> '@ | Out-File here_string_output.txt
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> cat .\here_string.txt
@'
foo : {abc}
bar : {123}
baz : {a1b2c3}
'@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $hereString = @'
>> foo : {abc}
>> bar : {123}
>> baz : {a1b2c3}
>> '@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $hereString
foo : {abc}
bar : {123}
baz : {a1b2c3}
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
```

How would the inverse, reading the contents of `here_string.txt` into the `$hereString` variable?

------------------------original form of question--------------------

Working with [sample](https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/import-csv-powershell/) data:

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $recordTemplate = @'
>> UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:LeeG@lazydev.com}
>> DisplayName       : {DisplayName:Lee Gu}
>> Title             : {Title:jr engineer}
>> UserType          : {UserType:Member}
>> IsLicensed        : {IsLicensed:True}
>>
>> UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:MeganB@lazydev.com}
>> '@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $recordTemplate
UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:LeeG@lazydev.com}
DisplayName       : {DisplayName:Lee Gu}
Title             : {Title:jr engineer}
UserType          : {UserType:Member}
IsLicensed        : {IsLicensed:True}

UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:MeganB@lazydev.com}
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> cat .\recordTemplate.txt
$recordTemplate = @'
UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:LeeG@lazydev.com}
DisplayName       : {DisplayName:Lee Gu}
Title             : {Title:jr engineer}
UserType          : {UserType:Member}
IsLicensed        : {IsLicensed:True}

UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:MeganB@lazydev.com}
'@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $newRecordTemplate = Get-Content .\recordTemplate.txt
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $newRecordTemplate
$recordTemplate = @'
UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:LeeG@lazydev.com}
DisplayName       : {DisplayName:Lee Gu}
Title             : {Title:jr engineer}
UserType          : {UserType:Member}
IsLicensed        : {IsLicensed:True}

UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:MeganB@lazydev.com}
'@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
```

How would the above template `recordTemplate.txt` be [read as a text fil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363884/4531180)e for [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75303629/4531180) as a [template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30936769/4531180) with either `ConvertFrom-String` or `ConvertFrom-StringData`?

So that the template itself can be read from a file rather than typed directly into the interactive CLI.

---

The file being parsed is `records.txt` with the first two records being:

```
UserPrincipalName : LeeG@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Lee Gu
Title             : jr engineer
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : MeganB@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Megan Bowen
Title             : recruiter
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True
```

Yes, that's `string` data, and, yes, looking to utilize `ConvertFrom-String` or `ConvertFrom-StringData` but first need to read a template from file.  The template is, I think, a [here string](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking-and-servers/9781789137231/6/ch06lvl1sec68/understanding-here-strings).

Comment: I think what you want is a dictionary of users where the key is the user name and the value is a hash table.  Is each user in a separate file or are the users combined into one file?  It would be better to post a sample of multiple users in one file.

Comment: I'm updating this q in a few minutes.  It's more than a bit jumbled.

Comment: A few years ago, I built a small function that plugs a table of actual values into a template text to produce a series of expansions.  The actual values come from a CSV file.  The template comes from a text file as you suggest in your question.  The name of the function is Expand-Csv.  you can find it on github and in here.  It's different from what you are looking for, but it might suggest some ideas.

Comment: how is this better than storing the data as Json or Csv ?

Comment: The data doesn't come as JSON nor CSV but as these value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

When I was coming up to speed on Powershell, I wrote a very simple template engine as an exercise.  Here is the process piece of that effort.

```
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
```

I invoke Set-Variable for every field in the csv file, and I invoke ExpandString for every line in the template file.  Powershell does all the heavy lifting.  Note that Set-Variable adds a dollar sign to the front of the variable name.

I make the whole function, named Expand-Csv, available on Github.  Visit [Expand Repository](https://github.com/Dcressey/Expand-Csv) to see or download the source code or a demo.